# How to get email read receipt in Magento?

Tags: php, email, magento-1.9

How to get email receipt using Magento? I tried below code but not working for me.

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$mailTemplate->setData("Disposition-Notification-To","kadamas49@gmail.com");
```

Comment: What does "not working for me" mean? What happens instead?

Comment: I am not receiving email read notification on kadamas49@gmail.com

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the recipient has enabled that feature? I've never sent such a notification in years, even if Thunderbird asked me to do it